# Anthos Bare Metal - Add Node / Resize Cluster

Tags: google-anthos

I'm testing out the Google Anthos Bare Metal and I'm wondering if anyone here successfully tried to resize or add nodes to their Anthos k8s cluster.

I've tried the `bmctl update cluster` after updating the config file and the new node won't show up..

Any help or advise is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
-MD

Answer (score 0):

In Anthos clusters on bare metal, you add or remove nodes in a cluster by editing the cluster's node pool definitions. You use the IP address of nodes to add or remove them from a node pool. You can use the `bmctl` command to change these definitions.

If the nodes are not visible after `bmctl update`, the node might have failed preflight check. Check the status of the node pool via the below command

`kubectl -n my-cluster get nodepools.baremetal.cluster.gke.io`

The new node added should be in the reconciling state.
Check logs for update cluster under the logs folder for more information.

Comment: Hi @Avinash, I can confirm that my new nodes are in "reconciling state" before. I'm going to recreate the cluster and replicate this and see if it will have the same results. THank you

Comment: Hello @Avinash, I've redo the steps on adding new node, and here is the details [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74133475/google-anthos-bare-metal-add-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74133475/google-anthos-bare-metal-add-node)